# Is there a way to customize the email content of AWS RDS notifications using SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, notifications, amazon-sns, amazon-ses, rds

The emails generated by SNS for RDS event notifications are not very descriptive. I'd like to modify/add content to the emails. I looked for a way and read that SNS does not support customization and SES can be used instead. But SES only shows options to add SNS topics for bounce,complaints and delivery. 
Could anyone please help me in understanding what I'm missing here?I'm looking for a way to receive customized notifications based on RDS events.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a built-in solution for this, but a relatively straightforward solution would look like this:

SNS → Lambda → SES

Configure a Lambda function to be triggered by your SNS topic that catches the notifications.  Within the function, you have programmatic access to the notification body.  Modify as desired, using code you write, or extract values for a template, then send an email via SES.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Since I'm not into coding, I've looked for some sample Lambda functions i could use for this but could not find anything relevant. Could you please point me to such sample functions, if you are aware of any.